# System.Security.SecurityException when using smtp.gmail.com

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

When using the code from [this well read post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my email", "my password")
};
```

I constantly get a System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission.

Does this code have to be used in some special hosting environment or am I missing somthing obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you are probably on a shared host that disables sending emails via SMTP (i.e. you are in medium trust). This is a CAS problem.

Comment: Ok, yes, I was a bit too quick to get frustrated about this. Fails on dev server (cassini?) but on iis it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email depends on how the SMTP server is configured.

```
According to gmail confiruged You need to remove this line of code
```

`UseDefaultCredentials = false;`

just comment this line and your message will be send.

```
 var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            // do not use this command
           // UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", fromPassword)
        };
```

Microsoft suggest not to use defaultcredentials when possible. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link for clarification.